# How to use @Valid with @PutMapping when Request Body is a List of dataclass in Kotlin Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, javax-validation

@Valid is not working with @PutMapping where Request Body is List of dataclass in Kotlin Spring boot

have added the library for it in the ***gradle.build.kts***

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
```

then tested for the below scenario it worked

```
@PutMapping(@Valid @RequestBody upsertData: UpsertData): ResponseEntity<String> {
        
        }

data class UpsertData {
    @field:NotBlank(message = "Name must not be blank")
    val naName: String,
    @field:Min(value = 18, message = "Age must be at least 18")
    val age: Int
}
```

but when I tried for below it is not validating the input

```
@PutMapping(@Valid @RequestBody upsertData: List<UpsertData>): ResponseEntity<String> {

}
```

I also tried by adding @Valid for the dataclass only but still this is failing...

```
@PutMapping(@Valid @RequestBody upsertData: List<@Valid UpsertData>): ResponseEntity<String> {

}
```

*Can someone please help me here...*

Answer (score 0):

you can try with removing Outer @Valid option

```
@PutMapping(@RequestBody upsertData: List<@Valid UpsertData>): ResponseEntity<String> {

}
```

or you can refer below sample code which is working for me

```
@RestController
@Validated
class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/srch")
    fun getSearchResult(
        @Valid
        @RequestParam(value = "term") terms: List<Term>,
    ): Mono<ResponseEntity<SearchResponse>> {...}
}
```

Comment: sorry, I have tried this as well but it is not working for me :(

Comment: updated my answer you can take reference ..if works you can vote for the same.

Comment: You can up vote to my answer for future reference to others

Answer (score 0):

try following because Kotlin declaritve is not same as Java;

```
@field:Valid
```